# Finding the most frequent number in an array using just a single pass

Tags: c#, arrays

So I am trying to figure an algorithm to search through an array with just a single pass to find the most frequent number occur in it. I have tried using two inner loops to solve it and it works but that requires going through the array in a loop of multiple times.

Right now, I am trying to figure another way of doing it by just "scanning" the array in one go to find the most frequent number. Anyone have any suggestion that will help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Most frequent Number in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279359/the-most-frequent-number-in-an-array).  LINQ-specific duplicates: [Find the most occurring number in a List<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355945/find-the-most-occurring-number-in-a-listint), [Find the most frequent numbers in an array using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169299/find-the-most-frequent-numbers-in-an-array-using-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LINQ you can simply use,

```
var mostfrequent = myList.GroupBy(i=>i).OrderByDescending(grp=>grp.Count())
      .Select(grp=>grp.Key).First();
```

**[`DOTNET FIDDLE`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uu5u8L)**

**EDIT**

Based on OP's requirement using Hashtable , it can be implemented as follows,

```
            int mostCommom = array[0];
            int occurences = 0;
            foreach (int num in array)
            {
                if (!hs.ContainsKey(num))
                {
                    hs.Add(num, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    int tempOccurences = (int)hs[num];
                    tempOccurences++;
                    hs.Remove(num);
                    hs.Add(num, tempOccurences);

                    if (occurences < tempOccurences)
                    {
                        occurences = tempOccurences;
                        mostCommom = num;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The commmon numer is " + mostCommom + " And it appears " + occurences + " times");
```

[`most frequent element in an Array`](https://www.csharpstar.com/csharp-find-the-most-frequent-element-in-an-array/)

Comment: What about in C# or Java?

Comment: @TomCold it is in C#!

Comment: @TomCold this is in C#

Comment: Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: I am thinking of using hashtable as well but that breaks the rule of what I want too.

Comment: you wanted solution in one line?

Comment: Not one line, just that the algorithm scans in one go and give the most occur frequency , using nested loops means it requires many scans in a few go.

Comment: Is there other way without using LINQ?

Comment: Thanks , which is better, hashtable or dictionar?

Comment: using hashtable has a slight benefit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089132/net-hashtable-vs-dictionary-can-the-dictionary-be-as-fast

Comment: Note that this answer likely scans the array 3 times (group, order, select), not just the 1.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your answer to the dictionary or hashtable method. Then I will mark it.

Comment: it has the logic, if someone wants they can click the link

Comment: This is definitely not an **O(N)** operation. As @kirklarkin points out, it makes multiple passes through the collection. One of those does a sort (which is likely **O(N log (N))**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionnary and set the key to the number then when you meet a number you already met add 1 to the value of the current number (which is the key) and when the array is finished pick the key with the highest value.

Comment: does that break the rule ?

Comment: or is it more effiicient to use hashtable?

Comment: No, you just need to loop through the array once

Comment: I think Sajeetharan's comment on the first answer is actualy what i just said but in code version ^^

Comment: Yea but i am trying to know what's the diff using dictionary or hashtable

Comment: A dictionary is a hash table. What "rule" does it break? You'd use a `Dictionary<int, int>` and extra variables that kept track of the current maximum winner and its count. Do that, and you should be able to do it in _O(N)_, i.e., one pass.

Comment: @Flydog57 Using hashtable would equally give me a one pass, O(N) complexity, am i right?

Comment: Yes. Start with two variables, one representing the currently most frequent number and the other its count. Then loop through your list of ints. If the current value is not in the dictionary, add an entry, key=the current int, value=1. If it is in the dictionary, increment it's associated value. After that (still for each int), Update those two variables if you have a new max frequency value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (you need to get the ValueTuple NuGet package for that tuple call signature to work):

```
 public static IEnumerable<int> ListOfInts = new List<int> { 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

 public static (int? mostFrequent, int numOccurances) FindMostFrequent(IEnumerable<int> ints) {
     int maxNumOccurances = int.MinValue;
     int? mostFrequent = null;
     //key is number (that occurs), value is number of occurances
     var counters = new Dictionary<int, int>();
     foreach (var num in ints) {
         if (counters.TryGetValue(num, out var occurances)) {
             counters[num] = ++occurances;
         } else {
             counters[num] = 1;
         }
         if (occurances > maxNumOccurances) {
             mostFrequent = num;
             maxNumOccurances = occurances;
         }
     }
     return (mostFrequent, maxNumOccurances);
 }
```

It goes through the integer collection once.  It builds a `Dictionary<int, int>` as it walks through the list, doing N lookups and N writes (either inserts or replacements).

If the list is empty, the `mostFrequent` part of the return will be `null`.  If there the maximum occurs more than once, you'll get the first one that's found.  If you want the last, change the `>` to `>=` in:

```
if (occurances > maxNumOccurances)
```

and, if you want all possible results, do something like this before the return:

```
var maxes = from pair in counters where pair.Value == maxNumOccurances select pair;
```